# SQL server Login failed for user

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

My MS Access Application uses SQL Database as backend.
The permission to SQL database is granted with Windows Authentication mode to a specific user group.
Most of users in the group can get access to SQL database but there are some users reported to fail for login in the database.

The error message:

```
Connection failed
SQLstate: '28000'
SQL Server Error: 18456
Login failed for user Domain\UserID
```

I spent sometime searching for the solution but I could not find one with the same problem.
Could anyone give me an advice on this?
Many thanks.

Comment: This question is far from reproducible or programming related. You can try [dba.se], but I doubt they'd be able to help you as well. For all we know, there's an active DENY LOGIN on the server for these users for some reason, which takes precedence over any allows

Comment: first check if the users are in the group with xp_logininfo ...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18751581/check-users-in-a-security-group-in-sql-server

Comment: Also check the SQL Server error log for related messages.

Answer (score 0):

To fix it you need a State of error message - explanation why it failed. It could be found in error message or SQL Error log if failed logins added
[Login failed for user - Error 18456 - Severity 14, State 38](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29613/login-failed-for-user-error-18456-severity-14-state-38)

Answer (score -1):

If the users are indeed in the group, can you try to delete and readd the group to SQL Server login.